# write formatted UTF-8 text file fortran

Tags: fortran, text-files

I'm trying to write in from fortran a text file.

I did this short test program but of course it does not work, because it does not create a text file that could be readable :

```
PROGRAM teste

 INTEGER(4) REC2,RECL1
 character(20) :: charI, wanted
 RECL1=10
 DO REC2=1,10
  OPEN(1,FILE='teste.txt',ACCESS="direct",RECL=RECL1);
  write (charI, "(A5,I4)") "hello", REC2
  wanted=trim(charI)
  write(1,REC=REC2) wanted
  close(1)
 END DO


END PROGRAM teste
```

I read lot of different thing but it's still really unclear how it should be written.

Do I need to convert to string before writing  ? if yes why ?

Comment: What do youbmean by "it does not work"? Avoid this phrase, it is not useful and does not tell anything. Be specific!

Comment: Yes, sorry, you're right. I mean it create a file but it does not create a readable file, formatted in a way that could be open by, for example, gedit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `open` statement you are opening a file for *unformatted* input/output.  Because you have specified `ACCESS="direct"` the default is for unformatted, compared with the default as formatted when connected for sequential access.

To make the file "readable" you need to actively open for formatted access, and provide a format for the writing:

```
open(1,FILE='teste.txt',ACCESS="direct",RECL=RECL1, FORM='formatted')
...
write(1,fmt=...,REC=REC2) ...
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
PROGRAM test

  IMPLICIT NONE

  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: ascii = selected_char_KIND ("ascii")
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: ucs4  = selected_char_KIND ('ISO_10646')   
  INTEGER :: ix
  CHARACTER(len=5,kind=ucs4) :: greeting = ucs4_"hello"

  OPEN(10,FILE='test.txt')    
  DO ix=1,10
     WRITE (10,'(A5,I4)') greeting, ix
  END DO
  CLOSE(10)

END PROGRAM test
```

... a commentary ...

```
PROGRAM test

  IMPLICIT NONE
```

All good Fortran programs include the line `implicit none`; the reason for this is explained in 101 Qs and As here on Stack Overflow and I won't repeat them here.

```
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: ascii = selected_char_KIND ("ascii")
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: ucs4  = selected_char_KIND ('ISO_10646')
```

The latest Fortran standard requires that compilers provide these two `kind`s of character.  I'm honestly not sure if `iso_10646` is the same as UTF-8 but if it isn't you're probably out of luck.  Here, I'm defining two parameters for identifying the character kinds to use later in the program.  For your purposes the first of these parameters is unnecessary but you ought to know about it too.

I suppose your compiler might support other character kinds, read the documentation.

(Aside: technically, there is a third character kind name, `default`.  This is likely to set the character kind to either `ascii` or `iso_10646`, most likely the former, but if this is important to you check your compiler's documentation.)

```
  INTEGER :: ix
  CHARACTER(len=5,kind=ucs4) :: greeting = ucs4_"hello"
```

In the second of these lines I've defined a character variable with the text `hello` and of kind `ucs4` (which, as you see above, is a local code for `iso_10646`).  Without the prefix `ucs4_` the string `hello` will be interpreted as being of kind `default` and then converted to `ucs4` when stored into the variable `greeting`.  In this case, where there is a 1:1 mapping between the (representation of) the characters in `ascii` and in `ucs4` the prefix is strictly unnecessary but there will be other cases where it won't be.

```
  OPEN(10,FILE='test.txt')    
  DO ix=1,10
     WRITE (10,'(A5,I4)') greeting, ix
  END DO
  CLOSE(10)
```

I've removed all the guff about direct access and writing at particular records in a file.  It's all unnecessary for what seems to be your immediate need.  So this loop will write `greeting` (ie the ucs4 string `hello`) and a row index  into the file `test.txt` 10 times.

```
END PROGRAM test
```

Comment: I understand much better thanks a lot, but, I still have the following error message : `GRAVARTXT.f90(8): error #6684: This is an incorrect value for a kind type parameter in this context.   [UCS4]
  CHARACTER(len=5,kind=ucs4) :: greeting = ucs4_"hello"
-----------------------^
GRAVARTXT.f90(8): error #6684: This is an incorrect value for a kind type parameter in this context.
  CHARACTER(len=5,kind=ucs4) :: greeting = ucs4_"hello"
-------------------------------------------^
compilation aborted for GRAVARTXT.f90 (code 1)`

Comment: @Dadep, this probably just means that your compiler doesn't support this kind of character.  If you `print*, selected_char_kind('ISO_10646');end ` you'll probably see the value `-1`.